# installing a light fixture on a wooden ceiling

Tags: light-fixture

I want to install a light fixture on a wooden, slanted ceiling.  There is no current light box.  How involved would this project be?

Thanks

Comment: Is there attic above the ceiling, or a 6" space then roof. You'll need space to work or things will get tricksy.

Comment: Your biggest challenges would be running cable from an existing nearby box to above the wooden ceiling and then to a wall switch. Otherwise, you may consider surface mounting the cable with wire mould. You will also need to recess and mount an octagon box into the wooden ceiling.

Comment: there may be low voltage lighting available for your requirement .... the cabling would be much thinner

Comment: Is surface mounted wiring (using either conduit or surface raceway) an acceptable solution here, or is a completely finished look a requirement?

Comment: If the bottom of the slant roof is on a perimeter wall with soffit AND there is proper ventilation space between roof deck and insulation, you can probably manage to fish wire up the slant to the desired location. Then you can go thru the top plates and down the wall to basement/crawlspace. It won't be fun, but probably can be done if there is no blocking.